# BCDEdit error, The parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bcdedit

I'm trying to add my SSD to the boot menu. I followed the instructions provided by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries#adding-a-new-boot-entry-). But I keep getting the same error.

This command gives me the error:

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "mySSD"
```

Then I ran `bcdedit /v` to see the `identifier's` GUID. This command also gives me the same error:

```
bcdedit /copy {c562ef5b-d0f6-11e8-bfb5-e86a64139893} /d "mySSD"
```

Error:

```
The copy command specified is not valid.
Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
The parameter is incorrect.
```

What should I do?

---

This is the output result of `bcdedit /v`

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-accb-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaab-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {c562ef5b-d0f6-11e8-bfb5-e86a64139893}
resumeobject            {c562ef5a-d0f6-11e8-bfb5-e86a64139893}
displayorder            {c562ef5b-d0f6-11e8-bfb5-e86a64139893}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf7b-c548a880142d}
timeout                 0

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {c562ef5b-d0f6-11e8-bfb5-e86a64139893}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6bb-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {6e6c06d5-d0f4-11e8-addb-e86a64139893}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {c562ef5a-d0f6-11e8-bfb5-e86a64139893}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was that those commands **only** work in **command prompt** and I was running them in **PowerShell**.

I ran `cmd` in my elevated powershell and then it worked.

---

Or as Vasily Galkin mentioned single-quote all parameters containg `{}` like

`bcdedit /copy '{current}' /d "mySSD"`

Comment: Bravo!! who could have thought of that!

Comment: Another workaround is single-qoute all parameters containg { or } like
`bcdedit /copy '{current}' /d "mySSD"`